# Doesn't bring your own key (BYOK) lose control of the key to cloud provider like AWS anyway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

My understanding is that by generating your own key and use that to encrypt stuff, it prevents a cloud provider from being able to read your data at rest. But before a cloud provider can use this customer managed key to encrypt/decrypt, it has to first have access to the key's plaintext. What stops a cloud provider from actually storing that plaintext and still has access to my data at rest?

Different cloud provider might have different approach to this, so I'm using AWS S3 as a reference here, which requires you to send the key in the request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

Answer (score 1):

In the [SSE-C](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html) scenario you refer to, the user provides to AWS the plaintext data and plaintext key (over https) and then AWS performs the encryption and discards the key.  The benefit to the user is that the user does not have to perform cryptographic operations.

If there is a concern about AWS having access to plaintext data or keys, the user can encrypt the data on the client computer and then send the data to AWS already encrypted.  This is the [client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) scenario.